# Ising model states taking on values {0,1} vs {-1,1}.

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, bayesian-network

I have seen descriptions of the Ising model taking on values {-1,1}, as well as taking on values {0,1}. I understand the {-1,1} representation is the more traditional option, though very reputable sources have presented the model where nodes are restricted to {0,1} (Wainwright, Jordan et al 2008). Both formulations have the same energy function. I am curious if parameter estimation for both would result in equivalent models?

Comment: The two versions **are** equivalent, all that counts is that every site can assume two values.

Comment: But consider the common interaction term: theta_{st}*z_s*z_t where s,t are neighboring nodes. If {0,1} encoding is used, this interaction term will capture differences between (z_s = z_t = 1) and all other options. However, if the {-1,1} encoding is used, the interaction term will capture changes due to whether z_s and z_t are the same, versus whether they are different from one another.

Comment: Indeed, which is why $z_sz_t$ is to be used only for $\pm1$-valued random variables. In the general case, one can use $$\mathbf 1_{z_s=z_t}$$ or any formula from a number of equivalent ones.